# Custom Validation on Multiple Inputs in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

After researching various methods to implement custom form validation rules in MVC I have found, what I originally considered to be a straightforward bit of validation, to be rather more complex that I anticipated.

I have 2 text inputs, one or the other (or both) need to be populated. If both are `NullOrEmpty` we need to throw an error.

I have found `DataAnnotations` to have it's limitations when attempting to validate on multiple fields, giving me highlighting on both inputs and throwing a single error. Is this some beginners naivity?

I also played around with `FluentValidation` and was unable to get the results I was after.

Currently I am throwing the error in the Controller using:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("PropertyName", "You need to enter a Property Number or a Property Name")
ModelState.AddModelError("PropertyNumber", String.Empty)
```

This gives me highlighting on both fields and server-side validation. I am now finding it difficult binding custom client-side validation without using DataAnnotations.

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this properly? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I need validation on the server/client, on both fields, with highlighting and a single error message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use this fluentvalidation.codeplex.com..Did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

**[Fool proof][1]** validation library covers almost all kind of validation scenarios.

```
[RequiredIf]
[RequiredIfNot]
[RequiredIfTrue]
[RequiredIfFalse]
[RequiredIfEmpty]
[RequiredIfNotEmpty]
[RequiredIfRegExMatch]
[RequiredIfNotRegExMatch]

Applied to a Model:

public class CreateUserViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Department { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfEmpty(ErrorMessage="error message"]
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```